# How to create a memory efficient Ruby Pipe class with lazy evaluation?

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation

I would like to create a Pipe class to emulate Unix commands in Ruby in a two step fashion. First step is to compile a pipeline by adding a number of commands, and the second step is to run that pipeline. Here is a mockup:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

p = Pipe.new
p.add(:cat, input: "table.txt")
p.add(:cut, field: 2)
p.add(:grep, pattern: "foo")
p.add(:puts, output: "result.txt")
p.run
```

The question is how to code this using *lazy evaluation*, so that the pipe is processed record by record when `run()` is called without loading all of the data into memory at any one time?

Comment: What do you mean, "without loading all of the data into memory?"

Comment: The correct term seems to be "lazy evaluation". I shall edit the question.

Comment: All of what data? The eight symbols, four strings and one Fixnum? What is it that you want evaluated lazily?

Comment: The lines in table.txt - it should only hold one line in memory at a time (apart from buffering). Pretend that the lines are multi-gigabytes of data each.

Comment: This article on the new lazy() method in Ruby 2 seems useful: http://magazine.rubyist.net/?Ruby200SpecialEn-lazy

Comment: @maasha What is your expected output of this code? Will table.txt be loaded by ruby and then passed to the cat command? In other words, what command does this code build?

Comment: The table should be loaded to Ruby and passed to the downstream commands in a lazy fashion similar to a Unix pipeline: `cat table.txt | cut -f 2 | grep foo > result.txt` but without using the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pp'

class Pipe
  def initialize
    @commands = []
  end

  def add(command, options = {})
    @commands << [command, options]

    self
  end

  def run
    enum = nil

    @commands.each do |command, options|
      enum = method(command).call enum, options
    end

    enum.each {}

    enum
  end

  def to_s
    cmd_string = "Pipe.new"

    @commands.each do |command, options|
      opt_list = []

      options.each do |key, value|
        if value.is_a? String
          opt_list << "#{key}: \"#{value}\""
        else
          opt_list << "#{key}: #{value}"
        end
      end

      cmd_string << ".add(:#{command}, #{opt_list.join(", ")})"
    end

    cmd_string << ".run"
  end

  private

  def cat(enum, options)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      enum.map { |line| yielder << line } if enum

      File.open(options[:input]) do |ios|
        ios.each { |line| yielder << line }
      end
    end.lazy
  end

  def cut(enum, options)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      enum.each do |line|
        fields = line.chomp.split(%r{#{options[:delimiter]}})

        yielder << fields[options[:field]]
      end
    end.lazy
  end

  def grep(enum, options)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      enum.each do |line|
        yielder << line if line.match(options[:pattern])
      end
    end.lazy
  end

  def save(enum, options)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      File.open(options[:output], 'w') do |ios|
        enum.each do |line|
          ios.puts line
          yielder << line
        end
      end
    end.lazy
  end
end

p = Pipe.new
p.add(:cat, input: "table.txt")
p.add(:cut, field: 2, delimiter: ',\s*')
p.add(:grep, pattern: "4")
p.add(:save, output: "result.txt")
p.run

puts p
```

Comment: Would love to see how you implement 'tee'

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html class. The `Pipe` class will stitch together an `Enumerator`, e.g. `add(:cat, input: 'foo.txt')` will create an enumerator which yields lines of `foo.txt`. `add(:grep)` will filter it according to regexp etc.

Here's the lazy file reader

```
require 'benchmark'

def lazy_cat(filename)
  e = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    f = File.open filename
    s = f.gets
    while s
      yielder.yield s
      s = f.gets
    end
  end
  e.lazy
end

def cat(filename)
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    f = File.open filename
    s = f.gets
    while s
      yielder.yield s
      s = f.gets
    end
  end
end

lazy = Benchmark.realtime { puts lazy_cat("log.txt").map{|s| s.upcase}.take(1).to_a }
puts "Lazy: #{lazy}"

eager = Benchmark.realtime { puts cat("log.txt").map{|s| s.upcase}.take(1).to_a }
puts "Eager: #{eager}"
```

Eager version takes 7 seconds for 10 million line file, lazy version takes pretty much no time.

Comment: Enumerator::Lazy seems more relevant - but I struggle getting it to work the way I want.

Comment: This looks very clever. I think we agree that `lazy` is the way to go, but I fail to see how a `Pipe` class could chain multiple commands.

Comment: And btw `lazy_cat` can be reduced to `File.open(filename).each_line.lazy`?

Comment: @maasha store the current enumerator in an instance variable and just set it to a new value: `@chain = lazy_cat(filename); @chain = @chain.take 10` etc and when you need the results just iterate over it.

Comment: @maasha yeah, `each_line.lazy` will only read required lines, forgot about it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

For what I understood you can simply read one line at a time and move this single line thought the pipeline, then write it to the output. Some code:

```
output = File.new("output.txt")
File.new("input.txt").each do |line|
    record = read_record(line)
    newrecord = run_pipeline_on_one_record(record)
    output.write(dump_record(newrecord))
end
```

Another much heavier option would be create actual IO blocking pipes and use one thread for each task in the pipeline. This somewhat reassembles what Unix does.

Sample usage with OP's syntax:

```
class Pipe
    def initialize
        @actions = []
    end
    def add(&block)
        @actions << block
    end
    def run(infile, outfile)
        output = File.open(outfile, "w")
        File.open(infile).each do |line|
            line.chomp!
            @actions.each {|act| line = act[line] }
            output.write(line+"\n")
        end
    end
end

p = Pipe.new
p.add {|line| line.size.to_s }
p.add {|line| "number of chars: #{line}" }
p.run("in.txt", "out.txt")
```

Sample `in.txt`:

```
aaa
12345
h
```

Generated `out.txt`:

```
number of chars: 3
number of chars: 5
number of chars: 1
```

Comment: Sure, but instead of "hardcode" the different steps like you did in this loop, I am aiming for some two generic methods (add and run). Thus it would work great in irb for a user (and all the cumbersome code should be abstracted away).

Comment: @maasha, I included a sample implementation

Comment: Yes, I see that can work, but you are letting the run command handle input and output explicitly instead of via `add()`.

Comment: It's just a matter of changing the class layout. The basic idea is the same.

Comment: I would really like to see how that can be done so it can be executed like my mockup.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20049201/3183101

```
require 'benchmark'

def lazy_cat(filename)
  e = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    f = File.open filename
    s = f.gets
    while s
      yielder.yield s
      s = f.gets
    end
  end
  e.lazy
end

def cat(filename)
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    f = File.open filename
    s = f.gets
    while s
      yielder.yield s
      s = f.gets
    end
  end
end

lazy = Benchmark.realtime { puts lazy_cat("log.txt").map{|s| s.upcase}.take(1).to_a }
puts "Lazy: #{lazy}"

eager = Benchmark.realtime { puts cat("log.txt").map{|s| s.upcase}.take(1).to_a }
puts "Eager: #{eager}"
```

This could have been simplified to the following, which I think makes the diff between the two methods easier to see.

```
require 'benchmark'

def cat(filename, evaluation_strategy: :eager)
  e = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    f = File.open filename
    s = f.gets
    while s
      yielder.yield s
      s = f.gets
    end
  end
  e.lazy if evaluation_strategy == :lazy
end

lazy = Benchmark.realtime { puts cat("log.txt", evaluation_strategy: :lazy).map{ |s|
  s.upcase}.take(1).to_a 
}
puts "Lazy: #{lazy}"

eager = Benchmark.realtime { puts cat("log.txt", evaluation_strategy: :eager).map{ |s|
  s.upcase}.take(1).to_a 
}
puts "Eager: #{eager}"
```

I would have just put this in a comment, but I'm too 'green' here to be permitted to do so.  Anyway, the ability to post all of the code I think makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This builds on previous answers, and serves as a warning about a gotcha regarding enumerators. An enumerator that hasn't been exhausted (i.e. raised `StopIteration`) will not run ensure blocks. That means a construct like `File.open { }` won't clean up after itself.

Example:

```
def lazy_cat(filename)
  f = nil  # visible to the define_singleton_method block
  e = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    # Also stored in @f for demonstration purposes only, so we examine it later
    @f = f = File.open filename
    s = f.gets
    while s
      yielder.yield s
      s = f.gets
    end
  end
  e.lazy.tap do |enum|
    # Provide a finish method to close the File
    # We can't use def enum.finish because it can't see 'f'
    enum.define_singleton_method(:finish) do
      f.close
    end
  end
end

def get_first_line(path)
  enum = lazy_cat(path)
  enum.take(1).to_a
end

def get_first_line_with_finish(path)
  enum = lazy_cat(path)
  enum.take(1).to_a
ensure
  enum.finish
end


# foo.txt contains:
# abc
# def
# ghi

puts "Without finish"
p get_first_line('foo.txt')
if @f.closed?
  puts "OK: handle was closed"
else
  puts "FAIL: handle not closed!"
  @f.close
end
puts

puts "With finish"
p get_first_line_with_finish('foo.txt')
if @f.closed?
  puts "OK: handle was closed"
else
  puts "FAIL: handle not closed!"
  @f.close
end
```

Running this produces:

```
Without finish
["abc\n"]
FAIL: handle not closed!

With finish
["abc\n"]
OK: handle was closed
```

Note that if you don't provide the `finish` method, the stream won't be closed, and you'll leak file descriptors. It's possible that GC will close it, but you shouldn't depend on that.